# how to train using conda-installed caffe with multi gpus?

Tags: pytorch, conda, caffe

my caffe is installed by the cmd:

```
conda install caffe-gpu
```

but how should I train my model with this pkg? In official docs( or some github repos), we will compile it and run it with

```
/home/xxx/caffe/distribute/bin/caffe.bin train --gpu 4 xxx
```

and when I used pytorch, I can also install with conda and using the module

```
python -m torch.distributed.lanch xxx.py
```

,but I cannot find this way in caffe, thx~

Answer (score 0):

The anaconda `caffe` package provides the binary `caffe`, which sits in your anaconda folder under `bin` and you should be able to just run it if you type in your command line:

```
caffe train --gpu 4 xxx
```